# How to retrieve the last 2 records from table?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a table with n number of records

How can i retrieve the nth record and (n-1)th record from my table in SQL without using derived table ?

I have tried using `ROWID` as

```
select * from table where rowid in (select max(rowid) from table);
```

It is giving the nth record but i want the (n-1)th record also .
And is there any other method other than using `max,derived table and pseudo columns`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from (select * from my_table order by rowid) where rownum <= 2
```

and for rows between N and M:

```
select * from (
   select * from (
      select * from my_table order by rowid
                 ) where rownum <= M
              ) where rownum >= N
```

Comment: I know that using derived table it can be easily done so i have specified in the question not using derived table concept !!

anyway thanks for the ans

Comment: what's wrong with using a derived table: see the classic answer on asktom: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:127412348064

Comment: nothing wrong with derived table !!
i just want to know is there any other solution for the same other than using derived table

Answer (score 4):

You cannot depend on rowid to get you to the last row in the table.  You need an auto-incrementing id or creation time to have the proper ordering.

You can use, for instance:

```
select *
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by <id> desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2
```

Although allowed in the syntax, the order by clause in a subquery is ignored (for instance http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html).

Just to be clear, rowids have nothing to do with the ordering of rows in a table.  The Oracle documentation is quite clear that they specify a *physical* access path for the data (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i6732).  It is true that in an empty database, inserting records into a newtable will probably create a monotonically increasing sequence of row ids.  *But you cannot depend on this.*  The only guarantees with rowids are that they are unique within a table and are the fastest way to access a particular row.

I have to admit that I cannot find good documentation on Oracle handling or not handling order by's in subqueries in its most recent versions.  ANSI SQL does not require compliant databases to support order by in subqueries.  Oracle syntax allows it, and it seems to work in some cases, at least.  My best guess is that it would probably work on a single processor, single threaded instance of Oracle, or if the data access is through an index.  Once parallelism is introduced, the results would probably not be ordered.  Since I started using Oracle (in the mid-1990s), I have been under the impression that order bys in subqueries are generally ignored. My advice would be to not depend on the functionality, until Oracle clearly states that it is supported.

Comment: whyso? rowid is unique within a table. See comment here: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:127412348064#345039100346541491

Comment: @davek . . . Rowid is deterministic, but it is not necessarily assigned in any particular order.  It provides the access path for getting to the row, not an ordering of the rows in the table.

Comment: thanks for the helpful explanation: that probably explains why Tonm Kyte suggests *adding* rowid to any order by to ensure it encounters no groupings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select top 2 * from table order by rowid desc
```

Comment: yeah i have gone through the `top` but it does not work with ORACLE !!
any solution to do the same in ORACLE would be thankful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rowid` as column in your table:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: ah, for some reason I was thinking your question was specific to MYSQL